# how do I update this statement to get correct date format in SAS?

Tags: sas

I need to get a date value from a file which is actually sas_data_file.sas7bdat.

```
proc sql;
    select max(a_date_field) into:date_version
    from "/some_linux/sas_data_file";
quit;

%put the date is &date_version;
```

That works and prints a date of "20870". To get a readable date I added the following just before the %put statement:

```
format date_version date9.;
```

But that gives the error

```
ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.
```

How do I format it to get a readable date?

Comment: What are you using the macro variable for? Perhaps you don't actually want it formatted as a date.  For example if you are going to use it later in code then the value 20870 will work better than 20FEB2017 since then you could use in code like:  `where date <= &date_version`   If you have 20FEB2017 in the macro variable you would have to add more code for SAS to see that string as a date.   `where date <= "&date_version"d`

Comment: This is part of a bigger script, which is why it's in a macro.

Comment: Not sure what that means. Obviously it is part of a program. And obviously you are putting it into a macro variable.  But what are you using the macro variable to do?  If you want to include is as just part of a string, like a title, then you should format it the way you want the string to look.  But if you are going to use it as an actual date value then the human friendly formatting does not matter.

Comment: The original script compares that date later on here:

month_diff=intck('month', SOME_DATE, &date_version); 

Yes I get your point I don't need to convert it for this to work, but I wanted to see it to verify. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `format=` option on the select

Example:

```
data have;
  do date = today()-365 to today();
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql noprint;
  select max(date) format=date9.
  into :maxdate
  from have;

 %put NOTE: &=maxdate;

--- LOG ---
NOTE: MAXDATE=22MAR2023
```